# how can I save Encrypted image into sql server?

Tags: sql-server, image, encryption

I'm doing module to save and retrieve images using SQL server database 2008 and asp.net with vb.net.
i already know how to do that
but I need to save the image encrypted into database because images are very secure and I'm afraid if I saved it normally as binary data any one can convert this binary to see this images.
if there is a way to do that please I need some help.

Thanks

Comment: What part are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.net comes with cryptography in the System.Security.Cryptography namespace. The examples on this page are helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For knowledge I found this 
[RSACryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.aspx)

this example for encrypt and decrypt byte array and this is suitable for image.

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am also working on the project to get image from user/frontend and save it to the SQL-Server database in encrypted type or change it into binary.
See the simple example of this :------------------------------------------How to save encrypted image into sql database. http://atul-dhiman.blogspot.com/2011/06/aspnet-using-c-repeater-control.html